# Get array of indexes in order of current values

Tags: c#, arrays

Excuse the long title but i'm finding it hard to explain.

**More info**

I'm making a game that makes the levels procedurally based on an array of `ints`.

The values in said `int` `array` are the range of possible GameObject indexes which are then used to generate the level.

I am now trying to use the same `int` `array` for the procedural color selections, but the amount of possible colors index range is less than the GameObjects range.

To solve this I'm lowering the `int` `array` to their possible lowest unique values while keeping the order they are in and then selecting the lowest values upto the value of the color `array` max index as a new `int` `array`.

**Expected Result**

```
//input
int[]{4,1,62,3,5,74,82,34} 

//lowest unique values in order
int[]{2-0-5-1-3-6-7-4}

//required array length(4) in order
int[]{2,0,1,3}
```

**What I have**

```
int[] startArray = new int[] { 1, 22, 67, 33, 12, 64, 23, 55 };

int nextIndex = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < startArray.Length; x++)
{
    int num = startArray.Where(n => n >= nextIndex).Min();
    int numIndex = Array.IndexOf(startArray, num);
    startArray[numIndex] = nextIndex;
    nextIndex++;
}

//startArr Output: 0-2-7-4-1-6-3-5

int requiredAmount = 4;
int[] returnArr = new int[requiredAmount];
int returnArrIndex = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < startArray.Length; x++)
{
    if (startArray[x] < requiredAmount)
    {
        returnArr[returnArrIndex] = startArray[x];
        returnArrIndex++;
        if (returnArrIndex == requiredAmount)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
//returnArr Output: 0-2-1-3
```

This works but i can't help but wonder if I am missing something and if there is an easier way to achieve what I am trying to do.

Comment: Maybe i'm stupid but i don't get it

Comment: @MarcoSalerno I'm not sure how I can better explain it :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you really care about is the index of the item within the ordered `startArray`. You can simplify your logic and eliminate the loops by using Linq.

Here is a quick example:

```
    int[] startArray = new int[] { 1, 22, 67, 33, 12, 64, 23, 55 };

    var output1 = startArray.Select(n => Array.IndexOf(startArray.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray(), n));
    //startArr Output: 0-2-7-4-1-6-3-5

    int requiredAmount = 4;

    var output2 = output1.Where(n => Array.IndexOf(output1.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray(), n) < requiredAmount);
    //returnArr Output: 0-2-1-3
```

And [here is a working Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/v7XHtD).

HTH

Comment: Awesome thankyou, I was just looking into Linq as the `Min` on mine was throwing an error for `0` in the `startArray` which yours solves.